# C++: Make VS2010 complain about "If" with "="

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ide

Is there any way in VS2010 C++ to have the IDE complain if I do something like

```
if (somevar = 2)
{
    ...
```

?

I try to pay attention to writing == instead of =, but not only using C++ but also VB and other languages, it just happens sometimes.

It takes really much time sometimes to find errors associated with my fault.

I think the possiblity that one really wants to write an if statement that also assigns a new value to a variable (as in my example above) is rather small. That is why I am hoping that VS2010 might have included an option that tells me about my possible flaw, but I haven't found one.

Is there any option like this?

Comment: if it involves literals, you could use an alternative style, like `(2 == somevar)`. that would issue an error if you mistype `==`

Comment: "I think the possiblity that one really wants to write an if statement that also assigns a new value to a variable (as in my example above) is rather small."  This does not mean it never happens ;)

Comment: If you specifically want to assign in the if, you can use another notation to signify you wanted to do it, e.g. `if ( ( somevar = othervar ) )...` Note that you cannot declare a variable in this way though, that is `if ( ( int somevar = othervar ) )...` will not compile, but `if ( int somevar = othervar )...` is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression
```

Just make sure you turn on all (not quite all on MSVS) warnings. (`project properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Warning Level`)

The alternative is using YODA conditions (`2 == somevar`), but that's ugly. :)

Comment: Great! Could you please tell me where to activate it? Or do I have to include it in my code directly?

Comment: @tmighty project properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Warning Level

Comment: Turning on all warnings may be a good idea in some compilers, but not VC++.  Otherwise you will be overwhelmed with warnings about things that occur in perfectly normal code.  You will even get warnings from the standard library.  Better to enable warnings on a case by case basis, at least on level 4.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley that's true, I don't know which level this particular warning is on (3 or 4 I reckon)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: 4, you can tell by the first digit.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley WAAAT!!! OMG!!! awesome. I didn't know that. (that does make sense though) :D

Comment: Phew, just found over 10 warnings like this, thank you very much! I am glad I asked!

Comment: @tmighty: In VC++ you have `#pragma warning` that lets you enable/disable individual warnings. This is often a better approach than global elevation of warning level.

Comment: @AndreyT I looked for that but it only has options to enable and set to default. :(

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: I'm not sure what you meean. In VS2005 I see `1,2,3,4`, `default`, `disable`, `suppress`, `once` `error`. I don't see an explicit `enable` option there. However, `1,2,3,4` options appear to let one to manually set the level of each specific warning. I.e. one can keep the global warning level at 3 and then "pull" `4706` to level 3 by `#pragma warning(3: 4706)`. This will effectively enable this waning alone.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the project name in Solution Explorer, select **Properties**, go to **Configuration Properties | C/C++ | General**, and set the **Warning Level** to **Level4**. You won't get an error but a warning:

> warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression